# Table doesn't align properly

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this annoying problem that the same table acts differently in different resolutions. One table that is a part of a page works fine, and everything is aligned just fine. The one that doesn't work is in a full width, because it is meant to be printed, so it is in a separate page. The problem occurs in Skills and Languages parts that "lorem ipsum" table cells don't align properly with "good/excellent" cells. The fix could be to increase the font size of the "entry_data" class, but I want to have it in a smaller size. What could you suggest to change here to fix it as I want it to work?

HTML Code

```
    <table id="cv_table_p">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="cv_head" colspan="4">Education</td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="entry_head">lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li class="entry_data">lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li class="entry_data">lorem ipsum</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="entry_head">lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li class="entry_data">lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li class="entry_data">lorem ipsum</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>                
            <tr>
                <td class="cv_head" colspan="4">Experience</td>    
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="entry_head">lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li class="entry_data">lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li class="entry_data">lorem ipsum</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>         
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cv_head" colspan="4">Skills<span>Basic/Good/Excellent</span></td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" class="entry_head">
                    <ul>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>                            
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td colspan="1" class="entry_data">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Good</li>
                        <li>Excellent</li>
                        <li>Good</li>
                        <li>Good</li>
                        <li>Good</li>
                        <li>Excellent</li>
                        <li>Excellent</li>
                        <li>Excellent</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td colspan="1" class="entry_head">
                    <ul>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td colspan="1" class="entry_data">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Excellent</li>
                        <li>Excellent</li>
                        <li>Good</li>
                        <li>Excellent</li>
                        <li>Excellent</li>
                        <li>Basic</li>
                        <li>Good</li>
                        <li>Excellent</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cv_head" colspan="4">Languages<span>Basic/Good/Fluent</span></td>    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1" class="entry_head">
                    <ul>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>  
                <td colspan="1" class="entry_data">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Fluent</li>
                        <li>Good</li>
                        <li>Basic</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>                   
                <td colspan="1" class="entry_head">
                    <ul>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
                        <li>&nbsp;</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>                   
                <td colspan="1" class="entry_data">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Basic</li>
                        <li>Basic</li>
                        <li>&nbsp;</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="cv_head" colspan="4">Awards</td>    
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="entry_head">lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</li>
                        <li class="entry_data">lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</li>
                        <li class="entry_data">lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>          
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS Code

```
body {
    margin:0px;
}
h3 {
    margin-top:10px;
}
#cv_table_p {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    margin-top:10px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
#cv_table_p td {
    width:25%;
    padding:0;
    border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
}
#cv_table_p .cv_head {
    background:#DCDCDC;
    font-size:1.125em;
    padding:5px;
}
#cv_table_p .cv_head  span{
    font-size:0.75em;
    float:right;
}
#cv_table_p ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#cv_table_p ul li {}
#cv_table_p .entry_head {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    padding:5px;
}
#cv_table_p .entry_data {
    font-size:0.825em;
    padding-left:5px;
    color:#4D4D4D;
    padding:3px 3px 3px 5px;
}
#cv_table_p p {
    line-height:150%;
    padding:0 5px 0 5px;
    font-size:0.9375em;
}
```

Comment: The basic problem is that you trying to use tables for layout. Don't. You have headings and lists.

Comment: what do you mean? if you mean the whole website layout, then no. im using divs to divide my website's content. this part is only a table of curriculum vitae that is easier to manage using a table.

Comment: I have to agree with @Quentin. Tables should only be used to display data. The CV content you are displaying could easily be laid out using divs, sections, uls etc. It may be easier to manage the way you are doing it but that doesn't mean it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#cv_table_p .entry_head {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    padding:5px;
    line-height:21px;

}
#cv_table_p .entry_data {
    font-size:0.825em;
    padding-left:5px;
    color:#4D4D4D;
    padding:3px 3px 3px 5px;
    vertical-align:top;
    line-height:21px;
}
```

Comment: it starts now from the top, but still doesn't align properly